# iTunes connect app name for TestFlight beta testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm developing an app for a client (developed couple apps for myself before). Client wants to be able to test the app in TestFlight during the process. To be able to do that I need to create a new record for the app in iTunes connect for a beta review and add the client as an external tester. I'm developing the app using my own developer account, client will submit the app to the App Store with his own developer account.

So do I create a record in iTunes connect using some temporary name for the app? And then client will use a real name, when it will be ready? Or is there some better/easier way to organize this situation, like using old testflightapp.com?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have an account with the old testflightapp.com site, that would be an easy solution. If not, that's not an option. They've stopped accepting new users. To use iTunes Connect TestFlight, you can upload the build to your account and then Transfer it over to his account at another time. You should choose the REAL name you want the app to use. That way, you'll be guaranteed to have that name for when you're ready to publish and you won't have to worry about trying to change it later.

Refer to docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: Registered a new account on testflightapp.com. I guess they are accepting new users. Added a new build and invited new teammates, everything worked perfectly. Thanks.